# Encrypt complete object with triple des

Tags: java, encryption, des, tripledes

I need to encrypt a complete java object. I am having a code which i have seen on internet which shows how to encrypt and decrypt text not the java object. So i was confused whether this is possible to encrypt complete java object. The code which i am using is below.

```
package security;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

/**
 * This class defines methods for encrypting and decrypting using the Triple DES
 * algorithm and for generating, reading and writing Triple DES keys. It also
 * defines a main() method that allows these methods to be used from the command
 * line.
 */
public class TripleDesEncryptionDecryption {
  /**
   * The program. The first argument must be -e, -d, or -g to encrypt,
   * decrypt, or generate a key. The second argument is the name of a file
   * from which the key is read or to which it is written for -g. The -e and
   * -d arguments cause the program to read from standard input and encrypt or
   * decrypt to standard output.
   */
    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
    public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES/ECB/NoPadding";
    private KeySpec myKeySpec;
    private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] keyAsBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;
    static String stringToEncrypt="";

    public void setKey(String myKey) throws Exception
    {
        myEncryptionKey = myKey ;
        myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        myKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
        mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
    }

    /**
     * Method To Encrypt The String
     */
    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }
    /**
     * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
     */
    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText=null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

            byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
    /**
     * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
     */
    private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Testing The DESede Encryption And Decryption Technique
    */
    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {
        TripleDesEncryptionDecryption myEncryptor= new TripleDesEncryptionDecryption();

        String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt(stringToEncrypt);
        String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Value :" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Value :"+decrypted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java-class called `SealedObject` ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html)) which exactly does what you want to achieve.

> This class enables a programmer to create an object and protect its confidentiality with a cryptographic algorithm.

There is only one restriction for the Object to encrypt, it must be `Serializable`.

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject(); // must be serializable

Cipher cipher;
/* initialize fully with IV, key and Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE */

/* encrypt `myObj` */
SealedObject sealedObj = new SealedObject(myObj, cipher);

/* decrypt `sealedObj` */
MyObjct decryptedObj = (MyObject) sealedObj.get(key); // `key` = encryption-key
```

Basically this class does the serialization with `ObjectOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` for you and automatically tracks the algorithm used for encryption.

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt bytes. Text is bytes, you can serialize a Java object to bytes, so technically it's possible (for example with an `ObjectOutputStream` connected to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

However it sounds strange, why do you think you need to encrypt an object, instead of the essential data inside an object?