# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 8 bytes

Tags: java, des, tripledes

i am getting this error while decryption i have go through the similar posts but i did not get any help from there. I want to store an object directly in a file with encryption for that i have posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399785/encrypt-complete-object-with-triple-des/25400892#25400892). But while using stream i am getting the same error as i am getting with string.

```
package security;

import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

/**
 * This class defines methods for encrypting and decrypting using the Triple DES
 * algorithm and for generating, reading and writing Triple DES keys. It also
 * defines a main() method that allows these methods to be used from the command
 * line.
 */
public class TripleDesEncryptionDecryption {
  /**
   * The program. The first argument must be -e, -d, or -g to encrypt,
   * decrypt, or generate a key. The second argument is the name of a file
   * from which the key is read or to which it is written for -g. The -e and
   * -d arguments cause the program to read from standard input and encrypt or
   * decrypt to standard output.
   */
    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF-8";
    public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
    private KeySpec myKeySpec;
    private SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] keyAsBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;
    static String stringToEncrypt="";

    public void setKey(String myKey) throws Exception
    {
        myEncryptionKey = myKey ;
        myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        myKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
        mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
        key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);
    }

    /**
     * Method To Encrypt The String
     */
    public String encrypt(byte[] plainText) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            //byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            //byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }
    /**
     * Method To Decrypt An Ecrypted String
     */
    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText=null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            System.out.println(myEncryptionKey);
            byte[] encryptedText = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText= bytes2String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
    /**
     * Returns String From An Array Of Bytes
     */
    private static String bytes2String(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Testing The DESede Encryption And Decryption Technique
    */
    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {
        TripleDesEncryptionDecryption myEncryptor= new TripleDesEncryptionDecryption();


        myEncryptor.setKey("tarunvermacdac@gmail.com") ;

        System.out.println("tarun1234".getBytes());
        String encrypted=myEncryptor.encrypt("tarun".getBytes());
        String decrypted=myEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+stringToEncrypt);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Value :" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Value :"+decrypted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't exactly know what you want to achieve, but I can at least explain the error you are getting.

**DES** and **3DES** have a *block-length* of `64 bit`. That means you must pass a *plaintext* which length is a **multiple of 64-bits** to the encryption-function. To achieve this you usually *pad* / fill up the last block of the plaintext with data of a certain pattern so that you can easily remove it again after decryption.

In your code you specify the encryption-parameters like this: `DESede/ECB/NoPadding` 
So you explicitly opt to not automatically apply any padding.

---

To fix this, just specify a padding mode (for example `PKCS5Padding`) instead of `NoPadding`.

**Note:** The cipher-mode `ECB` is not secure at all! You should instead better use:

```
Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // or "AES" instead of "DESede"
```

*(you must provide an additional `IV` though when using a mode like `CBC` or `CTR`)*

Comment: (Classic/Single) `DES` is indeed too weak, but `DESede` is Java's (or JCA's) name for what most people call Triple-DES and is still secure used with the full 192-really-168-bit key; `AES` supports 128, 192 or 256 bit key if you have the "unlimited strength policy" mod, see Oracle website. CBC is good for most cases but you need to change the code to provide the IV. And JCA uses the spelling `PKCS5Padding` although it actually implements the PKCS7 enhancement i.e. blocksize 16 as well as 8.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my mistakes. I updated my answer with your information.